# Javascript error: Uncaught ReferenceError: marker1 is not defined

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using the following code to cause the marker on the map to change when a user places his mouse over a div. Marker1 is definied within initialize() as follows:

```
var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({  

                position: new google.maps.LatLng(1.288693,103.846733),

                map: map,

                icon: "http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=1|c41200|ffffff"

            });
```

the function called onmouseover is:

```
function changeMarker(marker) {
            var icon = new Google.maps.MarkerImage({ url:"http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=1|ffffff|c41200"});
            marker.setIcon(icon);
        }
```

and the div is:

```
<div id="searchresult" onmouseover="changeMarker(marker1)">
```

I get the same error:     Uncaught ReferenceError: marker1 is not defined

**Attempt 2**

I tried adding the following line outside the initialize() function

```
var marker1;
```

and i get the error:    Uncaught ReferenceError: Google is not defined

My javascript is not great, do I make a mistake somewhere?

Comment: It seems your Google map JavaScript file is not loaded properly, check your current browser settings or try it in a diff browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you added `var marker1;` outside the initialize() function, be sure you don't still have the `var` on the usage of `marker1` inside the initialize() function.

By putting `var marker1;` outside the function you're giving the variable `marker1` a global scope.  If you also include `var` inside the initialize() function it will create a different local variable (scoped to the function) and the usage inside the div's `onmouseover` handler won't be pointing to what you expect.

Also, the `Google` error is probably that you've capitalized it.  In your init function `google` is lowercase.

Comment: Great, the     Google error is gone! Now I get the error: GET http://localhost/mysite/places/[object%20Object] 400 (Bad Request)

Comment: great i solved it! I got rid of var icon and placed the url directly in marker.setIcon(). I'm not sure why this works though...

Comment: @Nyxynyx The API documentation says Marker.setIcon can take either a string or a MarkerImage.  I doesn't say that the string should be an URL, but that appears to be the case.